# Excel version confusion

Tags: microsoft-excel, xml, file-format

I got an Excel file, actually it's a zip file which contains many folders and files including sheets in XML format. When I try to open it, **Excel 2003** says "The file is not in a recognizable format"

I've uploaded to Google Documents, Google recognized the format then I've saved as Excel 2003.

***I've already installed Microsoft Office Compatibility Pack.***

I renamed .xls to .zip then unzipped the content. Below are the unzipped folder content:

```
xl

Content_Types.xml 

docProps        

_rels
```

How can I open that Excel File?

Download: [excel.xls](https://rapidshare.com/files/239039541/excel.xls)

Comment: I just renamed .xls to .xlsx and Excel does open the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I expect this is new Office 2007 and higher format - so called OpenXML. I would try to change the zip extension (are you sure the extension is "ZIP"?) to "xlsx" and then try to open. You did not tell us your Office version, but I think Google Docs can handle this format, same with free LibreOffice. :-)

Comment: Yes, I renamed .xls to .zip then unzipped the content.

Comment: I just renamed .xls to .xlsx and Excel does open the file.

Comment: Nime, if this is the solution, please mark as answered.

Comment: It seems Excel 2003 (with Compatibility Pack) relies on file extension instead of file content. xls for Excel 2003, xlxs for 2007+

Comment: Nime, this is common in Windows. Many programs do not open supported file if it does not have the right extension,

Answer (score 0):

If you are running an older version of Office then you'll need to download the [Compatibility Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=3) from Microsoft.